# Jpa generate query to get a nextval from sequence

Tags: sql, jpa

I need to generate the this query using jpa

```
SELECT mysequence.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL.
```

I have

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT mysequence.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL").getFirstResult
```

but it always gives zero and never increments sequence itself.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `getFirstResult` on the query object and it's not what you think. See [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getFirstResult%28%29).

Try it with `getSingleResult`, that should work:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT mysequence.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL").getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 3.4 + Oracle 11

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT mysequence.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL").getSingleResult();
```

generates folowing sql

```
select * from ( select mysequence.nextval from dual ) where rownum <= 1
```

which is not valid sql and causes **ORA-02287**.

In my case only this works

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT mysequence.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL").getResultList().get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
      Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT mysequence.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL");
        return (String) query.getSingleResult();
        //Query query = 
    } catch (Exception e) {
//handle exception here
}
```